# How to Get Value of an element in a map Using Row and Column in C++?

Tags: c++, dictionary, iterator

I'd like to know how to get a specific value from a map 
that holds two vectors, using row and column strings.
For example, if the user enters "R1" and "C1" the string "1" is printed.
In this code, I am using array subscript to access vector.
It would be helpful if you could explain how to access it using iterator.

Sorry if this is repeated question.

Thanks.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

typedef pair<string, string> Pair;
typedef map<Pair, string> Map;
typedef vector<string> strVec;

int main()
{
const int COL_SIZE = 3;
const int ROW_SIZE = 3;

string row_array[ROW_SIZE] = {"R1","R2","R3" };
string col_array[COL_SIZE] = { "C1", "C2", "C3" };

strVec column;
strVec row;
for (size_t i = 0; i < COL_SIZE; ++i)
{
    row.push_back(col_array[i]);
    column.push_back(row_array[i]);
}

Map MyMap;
Map::iterator iterator;

string numbers[] = { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9" };
int numberIndex = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < ROW_SIZE; ++i)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < COL_SIZE; ++j)
    {
        MyMap[make_pair(row[i], column[j])] = numbers[numberIndex];
        cout << MyMap[make_pair(row[i], column[j])];
        ++numberIndex;
    }
    cout << endl;
}


string userInputRow;
cout << "Enter a row: " << endl;
cin >> userInputRow;


string userInputCol;
cout << "Enter a column: " << endl;
cin >> userInputCol;
```

}

Comment: consider using `map::find` or the `operator[]` for map or if you can use C++11 `map::at` to get the values from the map. Your map is keyed with pairs, so just take the userInputs, make a pair out of them and use `map::find` and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

```
Map::const_iterator item_pos = MyMap.find(make_pair(userInputRow, userInputCol));
if(item_pos != MyMap.end())
    cout << item_pos->second << endl;
```

**Edit:**
Please, fix this 2 lines:

```
row.push_back(row_array[i]);
column.push_back(col_array[i]);
```

Comment: Because you have a mistake in this 2 lines:

    row.push_back(row_array[i]);

    column.push_back(col_array[i]);

Comment: So what do I do? replace them by what?

Comment: OK. I got it. I used insert function. Everything is good. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You map is not holding two vectors, it is mapping from a pair of string to another string.
I wonder what is your use case for using such structure instead of vectors?

You already have the access to an element of the map in your code:

```
cout << MyMap[make_pair(row[i], column[j])];
```

Note that the [] operator will insert in the map if the entry does not exist, it is not always intended.

You can iterate on a map the same way as every container, and it is sorted on its key:

```
for(const auto &p : MyMap) {
    std::cout << p.second << std::endl; 
}
```